# Python pandas rolling mean without the window num fixed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I am looking to add two column [**std_dev**, **mean**], where the sample of the mean expands as the date continues for the specific location.

```
location   date              temp    std_dev    mean
NY         2014-02-01        60      
NY         2014-02-02        55      
NY         2014-02-03        70      
NY         2014-02-04        80      
LA         2014-02-01        80      
LA         2014-02-02        85      
LA         2014-02-03        75
```

I found a post that explains rolling mean/std and I was able to apply it to the table. However I receive an error for **std_dev** since the size of the location is not a fixed value. How do I reference the window size without it being fixed?

[pandas rolling on a shifted dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479800/pandas-rolling-on-a-shifted-dataframe)

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('location')['temp'].apply(pd.rolling_mean,4,min_periods=2).shift(1)

df['std_dev'] = df.groupby('location')['temp'].apply(pd.rolling_std,4,min_periods=2).shift(1)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html), e.g.

```
>>> df
   temp location
0    60       NY
1    55       NY
2    70       NY
3    80       NY
4    80       LA
5    85       LA
6    75       LA

>>> expander = df.groupby('location').temp.expanding(min_periods=2)

>>> orderify = lambda x: x.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()

>>> df['mean'], df['std'] = map(orderify, [expander.mean(), expander.std()])

>>> df
  location  temp       mean        std
0       NY    60        NaN        NaN
1       NY    55  57.500000   3.535534
2       NY    70  61.666667   7.637626
3       NY    80  66.250000  11.086779
4       LA    80        NaN        NaN
5       LA    85  82.500000   3.535534
6       LA    75  80.000000   5.000000
```

---

*Note*: It would be nice to use `.agg` here on `expander`, but as of version 0.19.2 there isn't sophisticated `agg` available on `groupby.rolling` or `groupby.expanding`, so it is not possible. See

- [**BUG/ENH: groupby.rolling.agg / Column(s) low already selected** #15072](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15072)

Comment: __Note__: I would _like_ to do this more nicely with `agg`, something like `expander.agg(['mean', 'std'])`.. but this isn't supported IIUC.

Comment: expanding supports .agg as of 0.19.0

Comment: @Jeff I'm in 0.19.2, I get an error with `expander.agg(['mean', 'std'])`->"_Column(s) temp already selected_". Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: ```In [1]: pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.19.2'

In [2]: pd.Series(range(3)).expanding(2).agg(['sum','mean'])
Out[2]: 
   sum  mean
0  NaN   NaN
1  1.0   0.5
2  3.0   1.0
```